# Turn QGraphicsView or Scene into XML/JSON

Tags: c++, json, xml, qt, serialization

I'm looking for an easy way (I think there isn't) to serialize a QGraphicsView or QGraphicsScene into XML or JSON.

I don't know if I'm supposed to save the View or the Scene. XML or JSON are fine I only need one of them. I just want to save a scene in a file to save it/load it

I found few stuff on other websites but it's seems quite complicated, or not really functional.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check out [this very useful tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-serialization-savegame-example.html) for working with json. Secondly, I think I've read you're working with a model-view based project?

If so, all model info should be saved and then there are two possibilities (depending on your design). Let's say you have created a model class `PlayerList` and you are showing all players using a `PlayerListLayout` or `PlayerListView`, a derived class from `QVBoxLayout`. Now there are two possibilities:

1. In each of the view classes, you have a direct reference to the model class. Well, all you need is to ask the model using getters (these getters would exist already, else you don't want to visualize the information). You don't need the json file, as long as you initialize your model first. So, for the `PlayerListLayout`, all you need to do is ask each `Player*` of that `PlayerList`-member and call `PlayerLayout::read(Player* player)` on all `PlayerLayout` members of `PlayerListLayout`. `PlayerLayout` will initialize it's new player-reference and ask the name, the capital, etc. to visualize it.
2. In one of the view class, you have no reference to any model class. Then you shall have to pass either the model or the json file to that view class, so you can get/read the information (again). This is a less clean way, which I don't prefer. It happened to me that I was creating large functions to read; that's when I found out something had to change. Reading and writing should be easy (if you divide the responsibilities in multiple classes).

I've had a Monopoly project, where I used this serialization as well, and the tutorial was really helpful. Secondly, I opened the `.json` file *outside* the model class (so in the view class), which you might want to consider as well. The disadvantage is that "*when you want wo re-use the model classes, but not the view classes*", you shall have to reimplement the opening and closing of a file in your new gui.

However, this way you create parallelism throughout your code, because returning true/false will happen in the view class of the main model (`MonopolyLayout` in my case), so the methods `Monopoly::read(...)`, `Board::read(...)` all behave in a similar way.